# Тривиальное серверное приложение

Tags: веб-программирование, web-apps, сервер, сокет

Всем привет.

Моя цель - написать довольно простенький сервер, который будет работать с сокетами с одной стороны и отдавать инфо из бд через веб-интерфейс с другой стороны. Что протокол взаимодействия через сокеты, что веб-интерфейс, очень простенькие, и я изначально думал, что напишу, к примеру, на С++ сам сервер, подниму на той же машине например ngnix и напишу несколько простеньких php скриптов как веб-интерфейс.

Но ведь это на столько тривиальная задача, что решается чуть ли ни в каждом проекте, наверняка уже есть готовый скелет подобного приложения, который я мог бы использовать. Я как-то пробовал погуглить, но ничего толкового не нашел. Может быть сообщество мне посоветует что-то?) Язык не важен, конечно же.

Answer (score 1):

Ну и в чем вопрос ? Вопросы с веб интерфейсом отпадают, вы сами описали схему, nginx `+` пару php скриптов.

Т.е остается непонятка с демоном на с++ ? Готовых реализаций море. А скелет везде один и тот же:

```
инициализация();
while(<прием подключения новых клиентов>) {
    while (<опрос команды от клиентов>) {
        ret = обработка_входящей_команды();
        отдача_ответа(ret);
    }
}
```

[Немного черной магии в UNIX](http://www.codenet.ru/progr/cpp/demons.php)

Comment: Не юникс, к сожалению win server =( но не суть в принципе :)
Меня как раз и интересует это "море" готовых реализаций. Реализация сервера на сокетах с подключением к мускулу есть и у меня (https://github.com/timramone/Garbage-Finder), но там на пример на каждое входящее соединение я делал fork. Сейчас я понимаю, что это не лучший подход..

Comment: У Вас реально сотни запросов в секунду ? 

Тогда потоки или асинхронная обработка. В противном случае, не заморачивайтесь, делайте на fork(). Для винды можно под Cygwin.

Comment: Ну не серьезно же. createthread вроде не очень сложно вызвать, или я в чем-то не прав?)

Comment: Вызвать несложно, отлавливать ошибки сложно.

Comment: Причем ошибки бывают очень интересными. Если не внимательно отнестись к разработке - у вас сервер может год проработать и потом лечь, долго вы будете искать ошибку =)

Comment: @avp fork... inetd -- и сервер превращается в программу, которая про сокеты ничего и не знает. Ежели мне не изменяет склероз, под cygwin'ом это работает.

Comment: Если обработка каждого соединения независима, не требуется какого-то хитрого восстановления при сбоях и нет заморочек со статистикой работы сервера, то для небольшой нагрузки это хорошее решение.

Comment: "Для небольшой нагрузки" -- просто к слову. Для тех, кто не знает, запуск процесса под виндами -- операция весьма не быстрая. Поэтому эмуляция fork'а (inetd туда же) затрачивает очень много времени по сравнению с fork в юникслайках.